# Error 404 formulario login en PHP junto a MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, error404, phpstorm

Muy buenas.

Llevo unos días intentando hacer una pequeña página para añadir usuarios a mi base de datos en MySQL. Antes de poder añadir los usuarios, he hecho otra página donde debo introducir un login correctamente para que me redirija hacia el formulario de creación de usuarios. La conexion en PHP la estoy haciendo con PDO.

Como no tengo mucha práctica he copiado código de algun tutorial, no sin antes intentar entender su significado, pero no paro de tener el mismo error 404, el cual no llego a entender porque ocurre. Trabajo con PHPStorm y MySQL 6.3. Cuando ejecuto el PHP para que se abra con mi navegador (Firefox) se abre sin ningun problema, pero cuando introduzco los datos y pulso el Submit, intenta redirigirme a la misma página sin resultado. Darle a actualizar no funciona para que recarge la pagina, pero si en la barra de busqueda vuelvo a la buscar la página, esta se abre de nuevo.

A continuación introduzco el codigo de PHP junto a HTML. El archivo de login se llama 'login.php' y donde tengo el formulario de inserción de datos 'formulario2.php'

El usuario creado es MySQL es 'manueh'@localhost', la conexion es 'formulario' y el schema es 'formphp'.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
if (empty($usuario) || empty($contraseña)) {
    $error = "Debes introducir un nombre de usuario y una contraseña";
    print $error;
}
else {
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=formphp";
        $dwes = new PDO($dsn, "manueh", "admin");
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $sql = "SELECT usuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND pass='$contraseña'";
    if($resultado = $dwes->query($sql)) {
        $fila = $resultado->fetch();
        if ($fila != null) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
            header("Location: formulario2.php");
        }
        else {
            $error = "Usuario o contraseña no válidos!";
            print $error;
        }
        unset($resultado);
    }
    unset($dwes);
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login Tienda</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='login'>
<form action='login.php' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class='campo'>
            <label for='usuario' >Usuario:</label><br/>
            <input type='text' name='usuario' id='usuario' maxlength="50" /><br/>
        </div>
        <div class='campo'>
            <label for='contraseña' >contraseña:</label><br/>
            <input type='password' name='contraseña' id='contraseña' maxlength="50" /><br/>
        </div>
        <div class='campo'>
            <input type='submit' name='enviar' value='Submit'/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo que espero que haga es que al introducir cualquier dato me de o fallo porque no lo he escrito o no esta en la base de datos, y en el caso de que los datos introducidos sean correctos, que pase a la página donde se encuentra el formulario de inserción de usuarios.

Comment: Manuel bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El error 404 ocurre cuando intentas acceder a un recurso que no existe. Imagino que aquí el problema está: o bien en `login.php` o en `formulario2.php`. Cuando te de el error `404` debes revisar la URL que hay en la barra del navegador y luego verificar que el archivo **existe con ese nombre en esa ubicación**. Por otra parte, tu código presenta una seria vulnerabilidad en cuanto a la forma de enviar la consulta: `SELECT usuario FROM usuario WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND pass='$contraseña'`. Un hacker podría manipular las variables e inyectarte una bomba...

Comment: Muchas gracias por avisarme de esa vulnerabilidad, la tendre en cuenta en mis proximos proyectos, aunque ahora mismo no es de gran preocupación ya que no planeo subir esta página, solo es para probar. Se lo que era el error 404, pero no porque me daba en esa situación. Al final lo he acabado arreglando agregando a PHPStorm la base de datos de MySQL y poniendo que usase XAMPP. Muchas gracias por la ayuda de todas maneras @A.Cedano